# How do we filter using DS findAll when you have multiple values for a parameter?

Tags: javascript, angular, filtering

What works:

```
    Rule.findAll({ property: 5596 }).then(function(response) {//stuff})
```

What I want: To get rules with property id 5596 and 3958

What I've tried:

```
    Rule.findAll({property: [5596,3958]}).then(function(response){//stuff})

    Rule.findAll({where: {property: {in: [5596,3958]} }}).then(function(response){//stuff})

    Rule.findAll({where: {'property': {'in': [5596,3958]}}}).then(function(response){//stuff})

    Rule.findAll({where: {property: {'in': [5596,3958]}}}).then(function(response) {//stuff})

    Rule.filter({where: {property: {in: [5596,3958]}}}).then(function(response) {//stuff})

    Rule.filter({where: {'property': {'in': [5596,3958]}}}).then(function(response) {//stuff})

    Rule.filter({where: {property: {'in': [5596,3958]}}}).then(function(response) {//stuff})
```

All of the kinds I tried throw console errors like:
    1) Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8888/v3/rule?bypassCache=true' from origin 'http://localhost:4000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    2) angular.js:15567 Possibly unhandled rejection
    3) Unable to parse gateways: undefined